# How to change variable value labels WITHOUT changing the variable name

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got a bar graph whose variable labels (a couple of them) need changing.  In the specific example here, I've got a variable "Sputum.Throat" which refers to samples which could be either sputum or throat swabs, so the label for this value should really read "Sputum/Throat" or even "Sputum or Throat Swab" (this latter would only work if I can wrap the text).  So far, no syntax I've tried can pull this off.

Here's my code:

```
CultPerf <- data.frame(Blood=ForAnalysis$Cult_lastmo_blood, CSF=ForAnalysis$Cult_lastmo_csf, Fecal=ForAnalysis$Cult_lastmo_fecal, Genital=ForAnalysis$Cult_lastmo_genital, `Sputum-Throat`=ForAnalysis$`Cult_lastmo_sput-throat`, Urine=ForAnalysis$Cult_lastm_urine, `Wound-Surgical`=ForAnalysis$`Cult_lastmo_wound-surg`, Other=ForAnalysis$Cult_lastmo_oth)
CP <- data.table::melt(CultPerf, variable.names("Frequency"))
CP$value <- factor(CP$value, levels=c(">100","50-100","25-50","0-25"))
CP$variable <- factor(CP$variable, levels = c("Other","Wound.Surgical","Urine","Sputum.Throat","Genital","Fecal","CSF","Blood"))

ggplot(data=CP)+
  geom_bar(aes(x=variable, fill = value), position="dodge", width = 0.9)+
  labs(x="Culture Type", y="Number of Labs", title="Number of Cultures Performed Per Month at Study Hospitals", subtitle="n=140")+
  coord_flip()+
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(),aspect.ratio = 1.25/1,plot.subtitle=element_text(face="italic",hjust=0.5),plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5))+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))
```

And for reference, here's a copy of the successful plot which it does produce:

[image: SamplePlot]

As I mentioned, all I want to do is change those labels of the individual values on the Y axis.  Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: Understood, but you still gave me precisely what I needed.  As the data I'm working with belong to others there's some sensitivity to sharing...

But thanks for your prompt answer ... it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to just change the axis label for that one category, try adding in this line

```
scale_x_discrete(labels=c("Sputum.Throat"="Sputum/Throat"))
```

be sure to add it (`+`) to your ggplot object.

Comment: Thank you, that did exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Using the helpful suggestion from @MrFlick above (with my thanks), I added the following to my ggplot code, which also gave me a word-wrapped label for the second label:

```
scale_x_discrete(labels=c("Sputum.Throat"="Sputum/Throat", "Wound.Surgical"="Surgical or \n Other Wound"))+
```

Resultant plot looks like this:
[Revised plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdBrs.jpg)